# How to delete rows in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm new to scripting and want to leverage Google's Apps Script for my Google Sheet.

I'm using a report connector from the Google Workplace Marketplace and it's bringing in unnecessary data just due to the default program.

I just need a script that automatically deletes the first 7 rows in my Google Sheet. It doesn't depend on the text, they just need to be removed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function drows() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(1,7);
}
```